# how to dynamically render view based from selected picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need solution and help, I am new in reactJS and react-native. I want to render component view based on selected picker value, here is the example of my code

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";
import { infoA } from "./InfoA";
import { infoB } from "./InfoB";
import { infoC } from "./InfoC";

export default class PickerSample extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item A" value=<InfoA/> />
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item B" value=<InfoB/> />
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item C" value=<InfoC/> />
        </Picker>
        {this.state.selected}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

is it possible to render the component as value of picker like that? or should I use `switch()` function or `.map()` function? or maybe is there any other effective way to achieve what I want?

**Edited**

Thanks to @Viet for fast respond, if it is possible to render the component as value of picker like the code example, may I know which part of the code goes wrong? it return error

```
Render Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

InfoA, InfoB, and InfoC Class Components are just a simple component with a single text component, here is the example code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default class InfoA extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Text> Information About Item A Explained Here </Text>
    )
  }
}
```

**Edited Again**
Using solution from @Saiful Azam with switch function, It still give me error

```
Render Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

When I change the return statement inside the switch function with `<Text>` Component instead, it works with no error. does it mean I do something wrong with InfoA/InfoB/InfoC Component? does it mean the Component not Exported correctly? or is there anything else goes wrong?

Comment: Yes  it possible

Comment: solved, thanks to everyone for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with the picker package but you can try this

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";
import infoA  from "./InfoA";
import infoB from "./InfoB";
import infoC from "./InfoC";

export default class PickerSample extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined
    };
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
 renderSelectedItem(){
   switch(this.state.selected){
     case 'A':
        return <infoA />
      case 'B':
        return <infoB />
      case 'C':
        return <infoC />
      default:
        return null
   }
 }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item A" value="A" /> // value type should be string or number
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item B" value="B" />
          <Picker.Item label="Information Item C" value="C" />
        </Picker>
        {this.renderSelectedItem()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: return error `Render Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: accept this answer as the solution, but neet to edit it. the answer will give the error as I mentioned. need to remove `{ }` from import infoA,infoB,infoC Component.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally render any component. Something like below is usually used to choose between 2 views. You can also use switch or if else stack for multiple views.

```
render() {
  return (
    this.state.selected ? (<View1/>) : (<View2>);
  );
}
```

Comment: missing '/' on View2 Component, thanks @NIV this worked so good for 2 views, I got stucked with multiple view, I think I will go with switch function, I appreciate if I could get some code example.